# converting a list of pairs in a column into two columns using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df with two columns as follows:

```
    ID  Country_pairs
0   X   [(France, USA), (USA, France)]
1   Y   [(USA, UK), (UK, France), (USA, France)]
```

I want to output all possible pairs of countries in two columns as follows:

```
ID  Country1    Country2
X   France      USA
X   USA         France
Y   USA         UK
Y   UK          France
Y   USA         France
```

Doing this gives me the output I want:

```
   result = pd.DataFrame() 
   for index, row in df.iterrows():
        x = row['Country_pairs']
        temp = pd.DataFrame(data=x, columns=['Country1','Country2'])
        temp['PID'] = row['PID']
        result = result.append(temp)
    print result
```

The dataframe is over 200 million rows, so this is a very slow since I'm looping. I was wondering if there is a faster solution?

Comment: For this amount of data, I'd recommend you to use Apache Spark instead. You could use pyspark to achieve your goal.

Comment: @HenriqueBranco I don't have access to Apache Spark. I do have access to a big memory HPC node that can handle such computations. I'm just looking for a smarter way to do this.

Comment: is there a way to change the way that the initial dataframe is formed?

Comment: @AbhishekMalik yes if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

# setup the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['X', 'Y'],
                   'Country_Pairs': [[('France', 'USA'), ('USA', 'France')],
                                     [('USA', 'UK'), ('UK', 'France'), ('USA', 'France')]]})

  ID                             Country_Pairs
0  X            [(France, USA), (USA, France)]
1  Y  [(USA, UK), (UK, France), (USA, France)]

# separate each tuple to its own row with explode
df2 = df.explode('Country_Pairs')

# separate each value in the tuple to its own column
df2[['Country1', 'Counrtry2']] = pd.DataFrame(df2.Country_Pairs.tolist(), index=df2.index)

# delete Country_Pairs
df2.drop(columns=['Country_Pairs'], inplace=True)

  ID Country1 Counrtry2
0  X   France       USA
0  X      USA    France
1  Y      USA        UK
1  Y       UK    France
1  Y      USA    France
```

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: @BKS update pandas to version 0.25 or greater.  The current version is 1.0.3

Answer (score 1):

give a trial at this:

```
explode_df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
split_country = explode_df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x['Country_pairs']), axis=1).str.split(expand=True)

# whether you would like to combine the results
res = pd.concat([explode_df, split_country], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```
result = df.explode('Country_pairs')
result["Country1"] = result.Country_pairs.apply(lambda t:t[0])
result["Country2"] = result.Country_pairs.apply(lambda t:t[1])
del result["Country_pairs"]
```

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Answer (score 1):

200 million rows is massive, no point running this computation on Pandas. As suggested in the comments, use Apache spark. or if it's in a database, u could possibly work something there.

The solution I proffer works on small datasets suited to Pandas ... take the data out of Pandas, use the itertools functions - [product](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [chain](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), and build back the dataframe. It should be reasonably fast, but certainly not for 200 million rows

```
#using the data provided by @Trenton
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['X', 'Y'],
                   'Country_Pairs': [[('France', 'USA'), ('USA', 'France')],
                                     [('USA', 'UK'), ('UK', 'France'), ('USA', 'France')]]})

from itertools import product, chain
step1 = chain.from_iterable(product(first, last) 
                            for first, last in
                            df.to_numpy())
res = pd.DataFrame(((first, *last) for first, last in step1),
                   columns=['ID', 'Country1', 'Country2'])

res


   ID   Country1    Country2
0   X   France         USA
1   X   USA          France
2   Y   USA             UK
3   Y   UK           France
4   Y   USA          France
```